# Adding a value to a method using a method

Tags: java, oop

I'm new to OOP and I've hit a brick wall. I have been trying and trying to get a program that enters price houses and adds fees and taxes. The code below is very hard to get to work, I keep running into "cannot find symbol errors" or "possible lossy conversion between double and int" etc. Can you please help me figure what is going wrong with the following class and tester code? This is only a part of the code that I am working on at the moment. Feel free to ask me questions on it and if needed I'll try my best to clarify what I'm trying to do. Thank you.

The class code;

```
// method that sets the number of houses
    public void setAmountOfHouses(int amountOfHouses)
    {
        //System.out.println("Enter the amount of houses for sale: "); // prompt

        if (amountOfHouses > 0) // if the number of houses is valid
            this.amountOfHouses = amountOfHouses; // assign it to instance variable number of houses
        else
            System.out.println("Please add at least 1 house to database... ");
    }

    // method that returns the number of houses
    public int getAmountOfHouses()
    {
        return amountOfHouses;
    }

    // method that set the house price
    public void setHousePrice(int housePrice)
    {
        if(housePrice > 0)
        {
            this.housePrice = housePrice;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid house price ");
        }
    }

    // method that returns the house price
    public double getHousePrice()
    {
        return housePrice;
    }

    //method to calculate fees and taxes
    public void calculateFees(int housePrice)
    {
        if(housePrice > 0 && housePrice <= 100000)
        {
            housePriceWithTax = housePrice + tax0; // no tax 
            totalAuctioneerFeeAmount = housePriceWithTax * auctioneerFee;
            totalHousePrice = housePriceWithTax + totalAuctioneerFeeAmount;
        }
        else if(housePrice >= 100001 && housePrice <= 200000)
        {
                housePriceWithTax = (((housePrice - 100000) * stampDuty1) + housePrice) + tax0;
                totalAuctioneerFeeAmount = housePriceWithTax * auctioneerFee;
                totalHousePrice = housePriceWithTax + totalAuctioneerFeeAmount;
        }
        else if(housePrice >= 200001 && housePrice <= 300000)
        {
            housePriceWithTax = (((housePrice - 200000) * stampDuty2) + housePrice) + tax0 + tax1;
            totalAuctioneerFeeAmount = housePriceWithTax * auctioneerFee;
            totalHousePrice = housePriceWithTax + totalAuctioneerFeeAmount;
            }
        else if(housePrice >= 300001 && housePrice <= 400000)
        {
            housePriceWithTax = ((housePrice - 300000) * stampDuty3) + housePrice + tax0 + tax1 + tax2;
            totalAuctioneerFeeAmount = housePriceWithTax * auctioneerFee;
            totalHousePrice = housePriceWithTax + totalAuctioneerFeeAmount;
        }
        else if(housePrice >= 400001)
        {
            housePriceWithTax = (((housePrice - 400000) * stampDuty4) + housePrice) + tax0 + tax1 + tax2 + tax3;
            totalAuctioneerFeeAmount = housePriceWithTax * auctioneerFee;
            totalHousePrice = housePriceWithTax + totalAuctioneerFeeAmount;
        }
        else 
        {
            housePriceWithTax = (((housePrice - 400000) * stampDuty4) + housePrice) + tax0 + tax1 + tax2 + tax3 + tax4;
            totalAuctioneerFeeAmount = housePriceWithTax * auctioneerFee;
            totalHousePrice = housePriceWithTax + totalAuctioneerFeeAmount;
        }
        System.out.println("Base house price is: " + housePrice);
        System.out.println("Cost of house with tax added is: " + housePriceWithTax);
        System.out.println("Total auctioneer fee on this house is: " + totalAuctioneerFeeAmount);
        System.out.println("Total cost of house with stamp duty and fees added is: " + totalHousePrice);
        }
    }
```

The tester code;

```
// Entering the amount of houses
    System.out.println("\nEnter the amount of houses for sale: "); // prompt
    int amountOfHouses = input.nextInt(); // obtain from input
    client1.setAmountOfHouses(amountOfHouses);
    if(client1.getAmountOfHouses() > 0)
        System.out.println("Adding " + client1.getAmountOfHouses() + " houses to database..." );
    else
        System.out.println("Returning...");

    // setting the price of each house
    int counter = 0;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("\nEnter the price of each house for sale: ");
        int housePrice = input.nextInt();
        client1.setHousePrice(housePrice);
        System.out.println("\nAdding house price of " + client1.getHousePrice() + " to database");
        counter++;
    }
    while(counter < amountOfHouses);

    // calculating fees and taxes
    counter = 0;
    do
    {
        client1.calculateFees(client1.getHousePrice());
        counter++;
    }
    while(counter < amountOfHouses);
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing that's wrong with this code is that every time you call `client1.setHousePrice(housePrice);`, you overwrite the price of the previous house. Your class only holds the price of one house. Therefore the last loop will calculate the fees of the same house multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: can you show us the output that you are getting?

Comment: @svasa Sure I'm getting this error message;

BuyAHouseIncTester.java:40: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
   client1.calculateFees(client1.getHousePrice());
                                              ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

Comment: Change your method declaration of calculateFees(int housePrice ) to calculateFees( double housePrice )

Comment: @svasa yeah that fixed the issue. Thanks very much. Just need to fix the do while loop when entering the house prices. My house price keeps overriding itself in the tester code. I'd rather you didn't tell me the answer but how could I fix this problem?

Comment: ofcourse it will. what is your requirement? can you state clearly, you need all the house prices in one place for each house? then you need an array.

Comment: Its ok i figured it out I did this...
do
       {
         System.out.println("Please enter the price of house " + x );
   int price = input.nextInt();
   client1.calculateFees(price);
         y++;
       }
       while( y <= amountOfHouses );